# Esta pergunta pode ser reaberta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

A pergunta [*Como usar sistema responsivo do Bootstrap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58619/3635) foi fechada há alguns minutos.

Porém eu discordei (votei para reabrir), pois na minha opinião é uma ótima oportunidade de explicar o sistema de GRID e apesar do autor mostrar pouco esforço, ainda sim podemos fornecer uma resposta de qualidade para a comunidade.

Porém percebi que o pessoal não concordou (ou não leu o meu comentário).

Eu sinceramente já vi perguntas da mesma "qualidade" serem respondidas e ainda ganharem muitos votos, eu realmente acho que a pergunta poderia ser reaberta, o que acham?

Comment: COncordo que pode ser salva, a edição ajudou. Voto para reabrir, venham essas respostas de qualidade! :)

Comment: Dará umas respostas interessantes, e pela minha experiência com Bootstrap, daquelas bem extensas :)

Comment: Só não posto a minha resposta agora, por que to um pouco ocupado e ainda falta alguns detalhes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finalizei com o voto final para reabertura.

Pensei exatamente a mesma coisa quando vi a pergunta, explicar o sistema de grid.

Só não reabri porque eu não teria tempo e não sabia se outros membros da comunidade estariam dispostos a fazer isso.

Isso mostra que nem sempre as coisas fluem 100% do jeito que deveriam, então é importante Às vezes lutar para que elas se ajustem e o meta é o lugar certo para isso.

Answer (score 0):

Concordo com você, existem pessoas que votam como uma pergunta ruim só por que não sabem responder e nem sempre é algo "extenso de mais". Pois bootstrap é bem simples. Só precisava informar as principais tags do framework e apontar um link para o manual.

Comment: Discordo, links podem ajudar, mas o bom é formular uma resposta bem completa já no ato.

Comment: Manual é necessário, se não a pergunta fica extensa de mais, não tem como colocar tudo na resposta. Seria bom colocar a estrutura e as tags de col-lg-12 (md,xs), as bibliotecas que precisa e o manual.

Comment: Um exemplo funcional e uma resposta longa mas objetiva acompanhado do link é legal, só link não é legal. Portanto me perdoe amigo, mas discordo, pois aqui é uma comunidade e não um local de "suporte apenas", devemos nos valer dos dois, ajudar o usuário e ao mesmo tempo tornar a resposta útil a comunidade. Eu pessoalmente estou escrevendo uma longa resposta para está pergunta, o problema é que está um pouco trabalhoso criar os exemplos.

Comment: Somente o link não seria legal, o que eu sugeri é colocar a estrutura do HTML com as principais bibliotecas e explicar como funciona as greeds (col-lg-12) etc.

Não tem como explicar um menu por exemplo, e também não faz sentido por que no manual é só copiar e colar. E já era...

Não posso criticar sua resposta, por que não vi ela. Mas se for explicar o less acho que fica inviável (pois é complexo). Por isto disse para colocar somente o básico e o resto apontar links para o manual (Menu, Slider, Less).

Comment: O less é um 3rd-party, não faz parte do que foi perguntado. Não tem sentido.

Comment: Você está muito mais tempo aqui do que eu, então confio na sua resposta. Desnecessário falar mais alguma coisa, só não acho que seja necessário dizer tudo na resposta.

Comment: Sim Felipe, você tem razão, não é necessário dizer coisas a mais do que é perguntado, vejo muito usuários que postam respostas enormes para perguntas que deveriam ter respostas mais objetivas, porém tem casos que é altamente necessário fazer uma resposta além do que foi perguntado. Obrigado por participar do meta :)